# How to notificate user by e-mail after permission granted

Tags: javascript, google-analytics-api

How can I to notificate user by email(do as google-analytics does from web-application), that I granted permissions.
I use this [method](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/accountUserLinks/insert?hl=en).
There is my request:

```
var request = gapi.client.analytics.management.accountUserLinks.insert(
        {
          'accountId': accountId,
          'resource': {
            'permissions': {
              'local': [
                'EDIT',
                'COLLABORATE',
                'READ_AND_ANALYZE'
              ]
            },
            'userRef': {
              'email': email
            }
          }
        });
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
MailApp.sendEmail(email,
    "notifications@example.com",
    "Permission granted",
    "You have new permissions granted: Edit, Collaborate, Read&Analyse");
```

Look: [How to send structured email markup using Gmail API and Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36811483/how-to-send-structured-email-markup-using-gmail-api-and-javascript)